# Devise redirecting after sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin, omniauth-facebook

Everyone, I am using devise with my rails 4 application and omniauth-facebook and active-admin.
When I am trying to sign-in exactly from sign-in page, after the authentication process, the page just refreshes (doesn't redirect to root_path as needed). But, when I am getting sing-in page from another(where authentication needed also), it works correctly (redirect to admin page, as example). This problem happens only when I am trying to login from sign-in page.
I have tried many override solutions, but it still doesn't work.
If it can help, I am using activeadmin authentication like default devise authentication, I mean:

```
 def authenticate_admin_user!
   redirect_to root_path and return if user_signed_in? && !current_user.is_admin
   authenticate_user!
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**return** with **and** nontrivial):

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
 if user_signed_in? && !current_user.is_admin
   redirect_to root_path
 else 
   authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

Comment: This method works fine, i have got a problem when i am trying to sign in from Sing-in page directly (not redirecting to the sign-in page from admin or other). Then i have refreshing /users/sing_in instead of redirecting to root_path